# How to set java-8 Nashorn javascript engine options for a single engine instance

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, nashorn

I have read that Nashorn supports some options but it seems [all of them are undocumented](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/8020015/webrev.01/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/resources/Options.properties.html).

They can be used by setting system properties but they are global. I want to set them programmatically for a single engine instance.

[Here you can read](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes) it is possible to specify options the way I want but that classes are internal so I get this kind of error:

```
"Access restriction: The type NashornScriptEngineFactory is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar".
```

I can't find a way to set those options with the java scripting API.

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem is eclipse protecting me from using internal classes and not exactly a problem using nashorn but I will concrete the question.

Is there a way to setup the options of a single nashorn engine instance without using nashorn classes that are not part of the [javax.script API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Can you give an example of the option or options you wish to change so that we can make the discussion more specific?

Comment: The most wanted option for me is `--no-java`

Comment: I was about to replicate Mike Clark's answer when I saw it appear. Does it work? What does java -version output?

Comment: Nashorn options can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jjs.html .

Comment: @wickund Those are not exactly nashorn engine options but jjs command line options.

Comment: @wickund I can't see `no-java` option there. And I already know the options as they are linked on the first line of the question. The question is not about them. I am asking how to use them on certain circumstances.

Comment: I normally don't wish to speak negatively, but we've done a lot of work with Nashorn where I am, and I find that in general it's poorly documented (what documentation there is is often fragmentary or confusing) and frustratingly, weirdly implemented. It's been the most problematic java package I've ever had to work on.

Answer (score 3):

The following program runs successfully for me:

```
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;
public class NashTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
        ScriptEngine engine = 
            factory.getScriptEngine(new String[] { "--global-per-engine" });
        engine.eval("java.lang.System.out.println('hello world!')");
    }
}
```

Make sure you're using a released version of JRE/JDK 8.

Comment: It works with maven/javac but does not work with eclipse (configured with the same JDK, the latest in both cases). In eclipse I get this error `Access restriction: The type NashornScriptEngineFactory is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar`